# Why doesn't tar ask before overwriting existing files?

Tags: command-line, tar, gnu

I lost a couple hundred lines of a Vim plugin I wrote and continue back up every so often because I extracted a `tar` file containing an older version. I decided not to use source control management when I wrote the plugin, since I only update it periodically.

Why doesn't `tar` ask before overwriting existing files by default? I'm guessing that there's some rationale behind why the default behavior is to overwrite files silently, since we usually want safety over speed and convenience. For example, we usually use `#ifdef NDEBUG`, not `#ifdef DEBUG`; similarly, I would expect `tar` ask me before overwriting any files, and for it to have some flag which I can use to tell it to overwrite files without asking me. Also, how can make it so that `tar` does ask me by default, without me having to give it any flags? I'm fine with using tools other than `tar`, if they support this safer default behavior.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "I decided not to use source control management..."  Well, there's your first problem.

Comment: It seems kind of silly to use SCM for every little project that I ever decide to do. Isn't it sort of overkill? I suppose that if it saves me from accidentally losing files, then it's a good tradeoff.

Comment: For little things (such as config files), I like rcs. It is a far cry from things like git or even cvs, but it does the basic stuff (i.e. keep a versioned history).

Comment: @void-pointer SCM is overkill for a single file that will never ever change. For anything else, it's appropriate.

Comment: `git` gives you the convenience of rcs (no need to worry about setting up a remote repository; just work where you are) with modern features and the ability to scale up if you decide to. If you already know the basics, there's basically no extra overhead for using it for "every little project".

Comment: @mattdm, git handles trees, RCS handles files. For config files, this an advantage of RCS (in most contexts, it is a source of problems).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same reason `rm`, `cp` and a whole slew of other utilities don't -- from early on, the POSIX design concept has always been to assume that the person at the console knows what they're doing and not to ask for clarification unless there's an actual problem.

In the case of `tar`, a look at the manual page suggests you could try setting the `TAR_OPTIONS` env variable to include the `--confirmation` flag.

Comment: Unfortunately, `--confirmation` is a little *too* safe.  It asks before extracting every file, whether or not it already exists.  Worse, it doesn't tell you if the file already exists.

Comment: Maybe alternatives like `--keep-newer-files`, `--keep-old-files` can be used instead?

Answer (score 11):

`tar -k` option asks for a confirmation if the file already exists. You could set it by default either by adding it to the `TAR_OPTIONS` variable (`TAR_OPTIONS="$TAR_OPTIONS -k"`) or creating an alias (`alias tar="tar -k"`).

Comment: my `tar (GNU tar) 1.34` with an option `-k` doesn't ask for confirmation, but it does fail with an error `tar file.txt: Cannot open: File exists`, if `file.txt` would be overwritten. So it still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked, but you can use `--backup=simple` option, which will append `~` to filename of all original files that would be overwritten.

And follow suggestion by @thinker25, to use `TAR_OPTIONS` or `alias` so it works by default.

Here is demonstration of `tar --backup=simple`:

```
$ ls
hello.txt  my.tar
$ tar --backup=simple --extract -f my.tar
$ ls
hello.txt  hello.txt~  my.tar
```